# Rails_admin capistrano deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

When I deploy my project i have some errors

```
00:19 deploy:migrating
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
      01 NoMethodError: undefined method `date_format' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::String:0x0000000686e768>
      01 /home/deployer/staging/blabla/releases/20170808132418/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:60:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
      01 /home/deployer/staging/blabla/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-0.8.1/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
      01 /home/deployer/staging/blabla/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-0.8.1/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:38:in `field'
      01 /home/deployer/staging/blabla/releases/20170808132418/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
      01
```

In file /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb I have this code

```
config.model 'Administrator' do
    visible do
      bindings[:controller].current_user.is_admin?
    end
    label I18n.t("index_admin.menu_label.#{@abstract_model.model_name.underscore}.#{label.parameterize('_')}")
    label_plural I18n.t("index_admin.menu_label.#{@abstract_model.model_name.underscore}.#{label.parameterize('_')}")
    object_label_method do
      :custom_label_method
    end
    list do
      field :id
      field :email
      field :fname
      field :mname
      field :lname
      field :phone
    end
    edit do
      include_all_fields
      field :image do
        visible false
      end
      field :phone_confirmation_at do
        date_format :default
      end
    end
    navigation_icon 'icon-eye-open'
  end
```

crash at line 59

```
 field :phone_confirmation_at do
    date_format :default
  end
```

Where I made a mistake ?

I have ruby 2.3.0
       rails 4.2.7
       rails_admin-0.8.1

Comment: From the error message, it seems that `phone_confirmation_at` is a String type (it was either declared as String for Rails Admin or the DB migration created a String type column. Can you check your migration and then your Rails Admin configuration?

Comment: at schema.rb
t.date     "phone_confirmation_at"

Comment: Can you check your DB manager client to double-check this information? schema.rb contains what the DB structure *should be*, it may not be totally true to what it *currently is*

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/g5wzxv) at phpmyadmin

Comment: but for example 
 t.datetime "created_at" 
maybe it's a problem

Comment: I tried  change_column :users, :phone_confirmation_at, :datetime 

Maybe this will help

Comment: That would be a good test to try this exact code but with the `:created_at` column (`field :created_at { date_format :default }`).

Comment: For some reason I cannot explain yet, your `phone_confirmation_at` column is resolved as a `RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::String` instead of `[...]::Types::Date` (defined here https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/date.rb#L10)